Implication as an Explanatory Relation Reference Request
Has there been anyone in Academia lately who has proposed the following form of logic:

Implication is interpreted as an explanatory relation between two propositions, so that implication is not equivalent to other signs in logic like conjunction or disjunction.
The negation of an implication is another implication where the consequent is negated.
The only propositions that can be evaluated as true or false are implications. Any other proposition is neither true nor false.

To illustrate what this logic would look like, consider the following statement: If all Xs are mammals, then all Xs are cats. This statement is false because its negation would be the following: If all Xs are mammals, then there are some Xs that aren’t cats. Now, the contrapositive would be the following: If all Xs are cats,  then there are some Xs that aren’t mammals. And I think the contrapositive is true, for if X is the set of cats, then the set of cats isn’t a mammal.

I don't agree with your illustration at all - your final sentence seems to mistake a set for its elements (just as {cats} isn't a mammal, {cats} isn't a cat either, so it doesn't satisfy the hypothesis of the contrapositive) - and your requirement 3 is strange to me, but it sounds like you're looking for connexive logic.

@NoahSchweber, I agree. I shouldn’t have chosen that illustration. However to salvage it, you could view cats as sets rather than something analogous to ur elements.

@NoahSchweber, also, thank you for the reference. It does satisfy what I’m looking for.

Carl Hempel attempted to set out a logic of explanation, but it is widely held to be of little use. Explanations are complex things that don't readily lend themselves to being expressed in a logical calculus. See, e.g. this SEP article, or this IEP article. I don't see how you would reconcile your requirements 1 and 3. If implication is a relation between propositions, don't these propositions have truth values of their own?

You can see implication as a sign, a marker when a is true you are sure that b is. E.g. in blood examination you have markers linked to diseases without being the cause of the disease.

This looks more like a set theory way of thinking. Suppose set A are mammals, and set B are cats. So the statement then becomes the following...
Statement: If X∈ A then x∈ B
The negation then becomes:
if X (not)∈ A then X (not)∈ B
These two are logically equivalent and they work for your analogy with mammals and cats. The contrapositive however becomes...
If X (not)∈ B then X (not)∈ A
In other words if X is not a cat then X not a mammal, and we know this is not true obviously. I think you may have it either backwards in that the negation is true, but the contrapositive is false, or the analogy you used for your illustration may not be the best as the fella earlier said. To answer your question though I think the basis for an implication is that it can be found and reasoned to through logical equivalences regardless of which logical equivalence. I hope this offered some insight, nice question!
